# Number of subtrees of root node in a B tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, language-agnostic, tree

The definition of a B tree I have read in various of books all contains the following

- Every node except the root node has to be at least half full
- If the root node is an index node, it must have at least two children.

I presume that the second special case is to allow a B tree to have, say, only one key and still be valid. However, if the B tree has many nodes, is it still allowed for the root node to have only two subtrees? Won't this break the guarantee of B tree like easy splitting and joining operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, if the B tree has many nodes, is it still allowed for the root node to have only two subtrees?

Yes, the root is special-cased because every other internal node has siblings that it can merge with.

Suppose that we delete a key and that, as a result, some internal node has too few children. We have two options in the usual B-tree algorithms: have this node take some children from its siblings or just merge siblings outright (possibly propagating the deficiency toward the root). Neither is an option for the root, so we just exempt it from the minimum children requirement. This increases the max height for a given number of keys by at most one, so the asymptotic running time of operations is unaffected.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more?